# If I have a Property_1 that has a getter & that getter gets a value from Property_2, does Property_1 actually hold a value/reference itself?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

If I have a  property (Property_1) that has a getter and that getter gets a value from a different property (Property_2), does Property_1 itself hold a copy of Property_2's value?

Or maybe Property_1 doesn't hold anything at all and simply goes and gets Property_2's value each time I ask for it?

Now lets say that Property_2 referenced an object instead of a value. When Property_1 retrieves that reference from Property_2, does Property_1 now have its own reference to that object?

I need to know this because I'm afraid that I should be setting Property_1 to null before my class is unloaded to help GC free up memory.

For example, I have a SecondaryViewModel and within it I reference my MainViewModel:

```
MainViewModel mainViewModel
{
    get 
    {
        return (new ViewModelLocator()).MainViewModel;
    }
}
```

Is mainViewModel simply being used like a method here to retrieve info?

Comment: Property getters and setters are methods. A getter returns a value, a setter receives an implicit argument named `value` that is of the same type as the property. Given that, it's not exactly clear to me what you're asking. Can you please provide a code sample to illustrate your first two questions? The answer to your third question is "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both getters and setters are methods.

In the case of auto-implemented properties, when you call a getter the value of the *backing field* is returned. Whereas, when you call a setter you assign a value to the backing field through the setter.

That being said, each time you want to retrieve the underlying field (a.k.a. backing field) a *method call* is made.

For instance, let that you have the following console application:

```
class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var customer = new Customer();

        customer.FirstName = "Foo";

        Console.WriteLine(customer.FirstName);
    }
}
```

If you try to see the IL code that is generated by the compiler you will see this:

[image]

More generally speaking, as [Rufus L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2052655/rufus-l) pointed out in his comment below, getters and setters may not operate on the same data at all. However, even if that's the case, they are still methods and that happens each time you use them is a method call.

Comment: Are you talking about auto-properties? If not, your first paragraph is making assumptions based on how the methods were intended to work. A backing field is not technically required, nor is it required that both the getter and setter operate on the same data. They are independent methods.

Comment: @RufusL You are absolutely correct. However in any case a property (a well designed one) hides the direct access from the field of a class. Even in the case, in which they don't operate on the same data, they are still methods. I will try to update my answer, in order to make this clear. Thanks